# Merging overlapping items in a list

Tags: python, list, merge

My goal is to merge overlapping tuples in the example list below.

If an item falls within the range of the next, the two tuples will have to be merged. The resulting tuple is one that covers the range of the two items (minimum to maximum values). For instance;                                                                              `[(1,6),(2,5)]` will result in `[(1,6)]`, as `[2,5]` falls within the range of `[(1,6)]`

```
mylist=[(1, 1), (1, 6), (2, 5), (4, 4), (9, 10)]
```

My attempt:

```
c=[]
t2=[]
for i, x in enumerate(mylist):
    w=x,mylist[i-1]
    if x[0]-my[i-1][1]<=1:
        d=min([x[0] for x in w]),max([x[1] for x in w])
        c.append(d)
for i, x in enumerate(set(c)):
    t=x,c[i-1]
    if x[0]-c[i-1][1]<=1:
        t1=min([x[0] for x in t]),max([x[1] for x in t])
        t2.append(t1)
print sorted(set(t2))
```

Derived Output:

```
[(1, 6), (1, 10)]
```

Desired output:

```
[(1, 6), (9, 10)]
```

Any suggestions on how to get the desired output (in fewer lines if possible)? Thanks.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please rephrase

Comment: What are your criteria for merging and overlapping? Still unclear

Comment: What should be the output if one of the inputs is `(3, 7)`?

Comment: @thefourtheye if one of the inputs is (3,7), the output will be [(1,7),(9,10)]

Answer (score 4):

Basing on answer from @Valera, python implementation:

```
mylist=[(1, 6), (2, 5), (1, 1), (3, 7), (4, 4), (9, 10)]

result = []
for item in sorted(mylist):
    result = result or [item]
    if item[0] > result[-1][1]:
        result.append(item)
    else:
        old = result[-1]
        result[-1] = (old[0], max(old[1], item[1]))

print result # [(1, 7), (9, 10)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem in O(nlogn)

First, you need to sort your intervals by it's starting points. After that, you create a new stack, and for each interval do the following:

if it's empty, just push the current interval
if it's not, you check if the first interval in the stack overlaps with you current interval. If it does, you pop it, merge it with your current interval, and push the result back. If it doesn't, you just push your current interval. After you check all the intervals, your stack will contain all merged intervals.

Comment: just demonstrate it and lets see the output.

Comment: I can't write the code in python, but what you are asking is a pretty famous algorithmic problem, which can be solved by this algorithm. I hope your Python knowledge allow you to implement it, since there is nothing too sophisticated

Comment: @m.wasowski O(NlogN) + O(N)?